# WebScraping only specific sections of a webpage in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I'm revisiting web scraping to try and develop a tool that can pull data from Databases.

Here I am using a substance dossier found at: https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/16016/7/1.

Here is a list of various Toxicological information that can be found in this dossier however I am only interested in Point of departure values (POD) known as DNELs here:

Basically copying an answer to me provided a while back I have the following code to pull the first POD.

```
Public Sub GetContents()
    

'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/16016/7/1", False
XMLReq.send
 
If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub

    End If
 
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText


'Retrieve Data

'POD Population and Route
Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sWorkersHazardViaInhalationRoute")

Debug.Print Info.innerText

'POD Type
Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("HorDL")(0)
Set data = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")(0)
Debug.Print data.innerText

'POD Value
Set data = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")(1)
Debug.Print data.innerText

End Sub
```

This works to pull the POD for the first route of administration: WorkersHazardViaDermalRoute

```
Workers - Hazard via inhalation route
DNEL (Derived No Effect Level)
238 mg/m³
```

This is fine but really I want to be able to tailor this to pull the DNEL and its value for each route of administration. As highlighted in blue here:

[image]

So for this Example, the entire desired output would be across 3 columns (not important it's in 3 columns right now though just wanting to pull the data):

```
Workers - Hazard via inhalation route, DNEL (Derived No Effect Level), 238 mg/m³
Workers - Hazard via dermal route, DNEL (Derived No Effect Level), 84 mg/kg bw/day
General Population - Hazard via inhalation route, DNEL (Derived No Effect Level), 70 mg/m³
General Population - Hazard via dermal route, DNEL (Derived No Effect Level), 51 mg/kg bw/day
General Population - Hazard via oral route, DNEL (Derived No Effect Level), 24 mg/kg bw/day
```

The issue I have is that I am using the class element "HorDL" to get this information but unfortunately this class is not limited to just the section highlighted in blue for each route. So ("HorDL")(0) works find but ("HorDL")(1) pulls the information immediately below for the same route.

For this reason, I suspect that using this class element to pull the information is not the best way to do this however I cant think of any other way to do this.

I already have a way to pull the relevant Dossier, so If this works It would make for a Neat tool that Just pulled the relevant Information. I have considered Pulling all the information and then applying a filter in excel but I don't think this is a particularly elegant solution.

Much appreciated for any responses.

Comment: Are all the DNEL consistent for other dossier or is it better to determine all DNEL available from the Toxicological Summary (excluding those with `Additional Information` and `Hazard for the eyes`)?

Comment: @Raymond Wu Better to determine from what is Available.

Comment: Try my answer below and see if it works for you then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This assumes that you only want DNEL with keywords `Workers` and `General Population` in the title and among them, exclude DNEL with `Hazard for the eyes`

Note: You should declare all your variables, insert `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce it.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents()
    Const DNELTitle As Long = 1
    Const DNELAssessment As Long = 2
    Const DNELValue As Long = 3
    
    Const resultFirstCell As String = "A1" 'Change the first cell address to insert the result accordingly
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change worksheet name accordingly
    
    'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/16016/7/1", False
    XMLReq.send
     
    If XMLReq.Status = 200 Then
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
        
        '==== Loop through each anchors and get the relevant ID for interested DNEL
        Dim anchors As Object
        Set anchors = HTMLDoc.getElementById("SectionAnchors")
        Set anchors = anchors.getElementsByTagName("a")
        
        Dim anchorsColl As Collection
        Set anchorsColl = New Collection
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 0 To anchors.Length - 1
            Dim anchorText As String
            anchorText = anchors(i).innerText
            
            If InStr(anchorText, "Workers - ") <> 0 Or _
                InStr(anchorText, "General Population - ") <> 0 Then
                
                If InStr(anchorText, "Additional Information") = 0 And _
                    InStr(anchorText, "Hazard for the eyes") = 0 Then
                    
                    anchorsColl.Add Replace(anchors(i).href, "about:blank#", vbNullString)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        '====
        
        If anchorsColl.Count <> 0 Then
            Dim outputArr() As String
            ReDim outputArr(1 To anchorsColl.Count, 1 To 3) As String
            
            For i = 1 To anchorsColl.Count
                Dim anchorEle As Object
                                
                Set anchorEle = HTMLDoc.getElementById(anchorsColl(i))
                outputArr(i, DNELTitle) = anchorEle.innerText
                
                'Loop through the anchor's sibling until it finds the DL tag to extract the values
                Do While anchorEle.nodeName <> "DL"
                    Set anchorEle = anchorEle.NextSibling
                Loop
                
                'Assumes that the assessment conclusion is in the first DD tag
                'Assumes that the value is in the second DD tag
                outputArr(i, DNELAssessment) = anchorEle.getElementsByTagName("dd")(0).innerText
                outputArr(i, DNELValue) = anchorEle.getElementsByTagName("dd")(1).innerText
            Next i
            
            'Write the extraction result to the worksheet starting from A1
            ws.Range(resultFirstCell).Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1), 3).Value = outputArr
        Else
            Debug.Print "No DNEL found."
        End If
        
        Set ws = Nothing
        Set HTMLDoc = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    End If
    
    Set XMLReq = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm getting an error 'invalid use of null' when I try to test out this code. Debug highlights For i = 0 To anchors.Length - 1 as the issue

Comment: @Nick Not exactly sure why but perhaps your MSHTML library doesn't like `querySelectorAll`. I have edited that to another method so try the edited code.

Comment: Both of your scripts run flawlessly in excel 2016 @Raymond Wu.

Comment: @SIM Thanks for testing this, I'm on Excel 2019 and `11.0.17763.2300` for MSHTML.dll (which probably matters as `querySelector`/`querySelectorAll` behaves differently depending on the version of the dll file)

Comment: Yep, right you are. It happens because of the whitespaces. The one that throws `Invalid use of null` needs to be declared as `mshtml.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection` instead of `Object`.

Comment: @RaymondWu Thanks for that it works now. I have actually added my own attempt at this below. I'm not nearly as fluent at VBA so it's more basic. Feel free to take a look and let me know if there are any issues doing it in this way.

Answer (score 0):

My own answer so Far.

Next I will have this loop through a list of Values to return the DNEL for each. Also need to include some sort of error handling.

```
Sub GetData()
    

'Start ECHA Search via XML HTTP Request

Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/registration-dossier/-/registered-dossier/16016/7/1", False
XMLReq.send
 
If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        
    MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
    Exit Sub

    End If
 
HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText


'Retrieve Data for General population

'Defines class element for each route
Dim Route(1 To 3) As String

Route(1) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaInhalationRoute"
Route(2) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaDermalRoute"
Route(3) = "sGeneralPopulationHazardViaOralRoute"

'Loops through each element

r = 4
c = 6

Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To UBound(Route, 1)


Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(i))
Debug.Print Info.innerText

Set Info = HTMLDoc.getElementById(Route(i)).NextSibling.NextSibling.NextSibling
Set Data = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")(0)
Debug.Print Data.innerText

Set Data = Info.getElementsByTagName("dd")(1)
Debug.Print Data.innerText


Cells(r, c) = Data.innerText

c = c + 1

Next i

r = r + 1


End Sub
```